# Providing rabbitmq.conf in a docker-compose file gives "sed: cannot rename /etc/rabbitmq/sedMaHqMa: Device or resource busy"

Tags: rabbitmq, docker-compose, config

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  mq:
    hostname: ${HOST_NAME}
    ports:
      - "5671:5671"
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15671:15671"
      - "15672:15672"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${USER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS}
    volumes:
      - ${CACERT_PEM_FILE}:/etc/rabbitmq/certs/cacert.pem
      - ${CERT_PEM_FILE}:/etc/rabbitmq/certs/cert.pem
      - ${KEY_PEM_FILE}:/etc/rabbitmq/certs/key.pem
      - ${MQ_CONFIG_FILE}:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
```

My rabbitmq.conf looks like this:

```
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
listeners.ssl.default = 5671

ssl_options.cacertfile = /etc/rabbitmq/certs/cacert.pem
ssl_options.certfile = /etc/rabbitmq/certs/cert.pem
ssl_options.keyfile = /etc/rabbitmq/certs/key.pem
ssl_options.verify = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false

ssl_options.versions.1 = tlsv1.2
ssl_options.versions.2 = tlsv1.1
```

However when I try to do `docker-compose up` I get the following error:

`cannot rename /etc/rabbitmq/sedMaHqMa: Device or resource busy`

I tried using old format of config file (rabbitmq.config) and it was not giving me this error, however I need to use new format because I need the password to be provided by during the startup via env. variables.

**EDIT Feb 20, 2018**

Here is a [list](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/issues/138#issuecomment-350081900) of currently available environmental variables in Rabbitmq docker image, and they are enough to setup TLS for both AMQP and HTTP (management API and Web Console)

Copying them in case the link will become broken:

```
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER
RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST
RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE
RABBITMQ_HIPE_COMPILE
RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_CACERTFILE
RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_CERTFILE
RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_DEPTH
RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT
RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_KEYFILE
RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_SSL_VERIFY
RABBITMQ_SSL_CACERTFILE
RABBITMQ_SSL_CERTFILE
RABBITMQ_SSL_DEPTH
RABBITMQ_SSL_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT
RABBITMQ_SSL_KEYFILE
RABBITMQ_SSL_VERIFY
RABBITMQ_VM_MEMORY_HIGH_WATERMARK
```

Answer (score 25):

This seem to be an issue with current rabbitmq 
Dockerfile. Particulary *sed* command seem not work properly on configfile mapped as volume. However as you have control over your `rabbitmq.conf` anyway, why not include default user and password to this file

```
default_user = admin
default_pass = YourStrongPasswort
```

and **remove** RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER and RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS out of your compose file. 
This is fastest work-around probably. Just tested, works for me (official rabbitmq:3.7-management).

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for testing with 3.7. In the end I might go with the workaround you proposed, but the ideal would be not to hardcode password into the config file, but to specify in .env - that would be easier for the ops team to do deployments - they would just need to `docker-compose up`. I would even prefer to re-write Docker file and build my own image if it helped to fix the issue. However it seems to me that Rabbitmq support only either environmental variables passed via `-e` or `.conf` file. Not both at the same time.

Comment: In the end I ended up providing all SSL parameters via environment variables, including user name and passwords, so I managed to avoid hard coding these values in the *.conf file, but instead just providing them in the .env file.

Comment: Also ssl options? Can everything be defined as ENV as well? Just for me to know.

Comment: Added a list of available environmental variables to my question which can be used to setup TLS for both AMQP and HTTP.

Comment: Can't work for open source projects as you cant put secrets into the conf

Comment: I have to recreate my docker service, then it worked. `docker service rm test` `docker volume rm rabbit_test`

Answer (score 3):

I recently faced the same issue with `rabbitmq:3.7.8-management` image.

I was able to work-around the issue by providing `advanced.config` instead of `rabbitmq.conf`.
`advanced.config` uses a legacy Erlang format, other than that, it worked perfectly for me. 
I also provided `RABBITMQ_*` environment variables, so it's not an issue.

In my case I was creating a cluster, but I believe the solution is relevant for all use-cases for now until `rabbitmq.conf` becomes available.

Comment: do you know if it is possible override values defined in rabbitmq.conf by providing same keys in advanced.config. If not, do you know how to specify TLS version in advanced config?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set username and password from environmental variable or from specific file use `-f` flag with - (dash) as the filename to read the configuration from stdin.which contains username and password.