# Using rabbitmq with docker in production

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq

I currently have a small server running in a docker container, the server uses RabbitMQ which is being run by docker-compose using the [DockerHub image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq).

It is running nicely, but I'm worried that it may not be properly configured for production (production being a simple server, without clustering or anything fancy). In particular, I'm worried about the [disk space limit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/production-checklist.html#resource-limits-disk-space) described at RabbitMQ production checklist.

I'm not sure how to configure these things through docker-compose, as the env variables defined by the image seem to be quite limited.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=secretpassword

  my-server:
   # server config here

volumes:
  rabbitmq:

networks:
  server-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: It depends on what OS you’re using as host for docker daemon. If it’s windows then the hyperV machine’s disk is the size limit for all your docker containers, in the case of Linux its the actual system If I’m not mistaken

Comment: I'm more worried about the disk_size_limit imposed by rabbitmq itself (~50MB according to docs) rather than docker disk size (I'm using Linux btw)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`disk_free_limit` is set in `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`, seems there is no environment available here.

So, you just need to override the `rabbitmq.conf` with your own one with docker bind mount volume to make your aim.

For your case, if you enter into the rabbitmq container, you can see:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~$ docker exec  some-rabbit cat /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
loopback_users.guest = false
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
```

So you just need to add `disk_free_limit.absolute = 1GB` local `rabbitmq.conf` & mount it to container to override the default configure, full example as next:

**rabbitmq.conf:**

```
loopback_users.guest = false
listeners.tcp.default = 5672
disk_free_limit.absolute = 1GB
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq
      - ./rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

volumes:
  rabbitmq:

networks:
  server-network:
    driver: bridge
```

**check if have effect now:**

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker-compose logs rabbitmq | grep "Disk free limit"
rabbitmq_1  | 2019-07-30 04:51:40.609 [info] <0.241.0> Disk free limit set to 1000MB
```

You can see `disk free limit` already set to 1GB.

Comment: After adding `- ./rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`, creating that file and executing docker-compose up -d, logs only show `rabbitmq_1       | sed: can't move '/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.confLNOkjP' to '/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf': Resource busy`

Comment: @angrykoala Sorry, I did not notice there is a rabbitmq docker official issue there, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48484501/providing-rabbitmq-conf-in-a-docker-compose-file-gives-sed-cannot-rename-etc), so the solution is remove your environment in docker-compose.yaml. In my example I also did not set it. To set the environment, set `default_user = admin` & `default_pass = YourStrongPasswort` in your `rabbitmq.conf` also.

Comment: And, another solution is not use volume, use you own dockerfile, in this dockerfile, use `COPY ./rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf`, then in compose.yaml, use your own docker image which base from the official rabbitmq docker image. In this way, you can still use `environment` in your docker-compose.yaml